# how to validate if atleast 2 out of 5 combo boxes are selected c#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have 5 combo boxes on my form and I want to validate the form by checking that user has selected at least 2 out of these 5 combo boxes. How can I write this condition in c# code?

I searched a lot on google and different sites but they all talk about selecting multiple values in a single combo box or something that is not my requirement.

Can somebody throw some light here? Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any code of things you've tried?

Comment: I can't begin writing this condition specifically.. 'at least 2 out of 5'

Comment: Is it windows or ASP.NET, which framework?

Comment: Your question does not even try to show what you attempted, in your code, to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count the number of selected combo boxes using a conditional expression.

This expression

```
int oneIfSelected = comboBox1.Selectedindex != -1 ? 1 : 0;
```

will be `1` if `comboBox1` has an item selected; otherwise it would be zero.

Now you can construct a checked count expression like this:

```
int totalSelected = (comboBox1.Selectedindex != -1 ? 1 : 0)
                  + (comboBox2.Selectedindex != -1 ? 1 : 0)
                  + (comboBox3.Selectedindex != -1 ? 1 : 0)
                  + (comboBox4.Selectedindex != -1 ? 1 : 0)
                  + (comboBox5.Selectedindex != -1 ? 1 : 0);
```

If at least two out of five combo boxes have a value selected, `totalSelected` would be at least 2. So you can do the checking like below :

```
if(totalSelected >= 2)
{
 //Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could subscribe a method to the `SelectedValueChanged` event of all the combo boxes you have and there update the info about that combo, something like:

```
Dictionary<ComboBox, int> combosInfo = new Dictionary<ComboBox, int>();

public void combo_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ComboBox c = sender as ComboBox;
    if (c != null) {
        combosInfo[c] = 1;
    }
}
```

Then, at where you want to check how many of them have a value selected you can do:

```
int count = combosInfo.Values.Sum();
```

Remember to include the statement `using System.Linq` to find the extension method `Sum`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering but the above answer seems pretty simple and straightforward.